# DestilBERT for Classification on CPU run time

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I've been doing some time profiling on a pre tuned DestilBERT for sequence classification and was wondering if anyone could help me understand the results i am getting. For reference i am calling the model i have fine tuned via the HuggingFace Trainer and am calling a single line at inference with varying lengths performing 10 loops on the same input and averaging the results. I am not including the model init in this timing.

When i set my tokenizer to truncate with a max length of 512 my run time appears to increase per iteration to around 0.84 seconds which is approximately 0.4 seconds longer.

However when i don't set my data to truncate i get a much faster run time. I assume this is because my token is smaller than 512 and i'm happy with that. I've done test where i slowly increase my token limit and each time the run time increases up towards the 512 mark. My confusion starts when i have a token of 800 in length yet my run time is smaller than that of 512. The only explanation i have for this is that as its over the 512 token limit for DestilBERT its splitting up the text into smaller chunks and running in parallel? does that sounds logical?

I don't really know any way of checking this and can't seem to find much resources on the web for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

fine tuned a DestilBERT model and i'm running a time profiling. I've tried slowly increasing the length to check it wasn't anything with the truncation which shows that its the token count not the truncation method.

Comment: It seems interesting. Can you please include your profiling setup for timing as a code snippet or sth ? Btw, by default I'd have expected for model to throw an exception for inputs longer than 512 tokens

Comment: I can't provide setup for profiling as its an internal resource but the increase is coming directly from this line in my code: multiclass_model(**encodings).

Yeah it is odd that it isn't raising an issue and isn't really something i've thought too much about tbh, as the results were looking really strong. I've checked my model config and the token limit is 512 but it doesn't throw any error. I've got desperate and asked CHATGPT which says "DistilBERT uses a technique called "sliding window" to handle inputs longer than its maximum sequence length" so perhaps its related to this

Comment: Im an idiot, had the truncation turned on but not in my prod pipeline. Didn't even notice is was throwing an error about token lenght! thanks for your help